# Number of Different Inscribed Triangles in a Circle with a Given Number of Equidistante Points on It

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Is there a formula for calculating the number of different inscribed triangles in a circle with a given number of equidistante points on it? By "different" I mean that a triangle can't be rotated or reflected onto another.

Consider the following example: If there are $10$ points, the answer is $8$ triangles;

[image: examples]

Note: I'v had a look at [finding number of triangles inscribed in a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245124/finding-number-of-triangles-inscribed-in-a-circle) but it's not exactly what I want. The formula given is for every triangles, regardless of rotation or reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $n$ equally spaced points on the circle, then the three legs of your triangle cross $a$, $b$, and $c$ points, where $a+b+c=n$.  Since you're identifying reflections and rotations, permutations of $(a,b,c)$ all represent the same triangle.  So you want the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly three parts.  This is fairly well known; e.g., see [this derivation](https://benvitalenum3ers.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/number-of-partitions-of-n-into-exactly-3-parts/) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107460/partitions-of-n-with-exactly-3-parts).  The simplest expression seems to be by cases based on $n$ (mod $6$):
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
n^2/12 &\qquad&n\equiv 0 \text{ mod 6} \\
n^2/12 - 1/12 &\qquad& n\equiv 1 \text{ mod 6} \\
n^2/12 - 1/3 &\qquad& n\equiv 2 \text{ mod 6} \\
n^2/12 + 1/4 &\qquad& n\equiv 3 \text{ mod 6} \\
n^2/12 - 1/3 &\qquad& n\equiv 4 \text{ mod 6} \\
n^2/12 - 1/12 &\qquad& n\equiv 5 \text{ mod 6} \\
\end{cases}
$$
More briefly, $f(n)$ is the closest integer to $n^2/12$.